# Java: Killing a thread launched as a Runnable by ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

I have a system which launches workers when it receives a call from a webservice to do so. The workers are launched by an ExecutorService, the class being launched implements Runnable. However, if the worker times out, I am unable to actually kill the worker, which is leading to resource issues on my system.

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    public void internalCall() {
        logger.info("B-1");
        //Some business code which may take too long
        // <...>
        logger.info("B-2");
    }

    public void launch() {
        // Wrapper
        Callable<Object> callable = new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                internalCall();
                return null;
            }
        };

        // Submit
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Object> future = executor.submit(callable);

        try {
            // Wait
            future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e) {
            logger.warn("Timeout");
        }
        finally {
            logger.info("A-1");
            executor.shutdownNow();
            future.cancel(true);
            logger.info("A-2");
        }
    }
}
```

If the worker times out, I would expect the following log message:

```
INFO | B-1
WARN | Timeout
INFO | A-1
INFO | A-2
```

Followed by the service remaining idle until another worker request comes in. However, despite calling shutdownNow() and cancel() on the ExecutorService and Future respectably, the worker continues:

```
INFO | B-1
WARN | Timeout
INFO | A-1
INFO | A-2
INFO | B-2
```

I've looked around and there are a number of other, similar questions about killing threads, with the general consensus being that you shouldn't do it. However, this is a class which may be extended, with the intent to override the internalCall() - meaning I can't rely on internalCall to police itself and check Thread.isInterrupted() or anything like that.

I'd like to just force kill things from the launch() method by attacking the furure or executor object.

Comment: The worker threads are maintained by the executor service - they are just 'borrowed' by the submitted tasks and usually reused for many task executions. You are not allowed to simply 'kill' them!

Comment: So why doesn't stopping the executor service stop the threads then?

Comment: The ExecutorService tries to stop the threads but there is no guarantee it will if you have errant code. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

N.B.

> **What if a thread doesn't respond to Thread.interrupt?**
>
> In some cases, you can use application specific tricks. For example,
>   if a thread is waiting on a known socket, you can close the socket to
>   cause the thread to return immediately. Unfortunately, there really
>   isn't any technique that works in general. **It should be noted that in
>   all situations where a waiting thread doesn't respond to
>   Thread.interrupt, it wouldn't respond to Thread.stop either.** Such
>   cases include deliberate denial-of-service attacks, and I/O operations
>   for which thread.stop and thread.interrupt do not work properly.
>   - [Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

So what have we learned... In Java do not run third party code that you really can't trust in the same execution as your primary application. Also even if Thread.stop did work you still have a whole bunch of other things that are far worse than threads not checking interrupt status (ie code calling `System.exit(0)`).

What I recommend you do for third party code that you can't trust is either:

- Run the third party code as an evaluated language run by Java that you control the execution of. Some examples are: rules languages like Drools or logicless templating language like JMustache.
- Run the third party code in a separate execution and use your operating system to kill the process and IPC such as sockets for communication.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `future.cancel(true)` does not kill the running thread. It only attempts to stop its execution in a "polite manner".

What it does it sends interrupt signal, more or less, same way as if you called `yourthread.interrupt()` somewhere in your code.

It will stop the processing only if the code inside the run() method checks for the interruption. So inside your `internalCall()` you need to check every now and then if the thread was not interrupted by calling `Thread.interrupted()` and stops the execution. The interrupt will also stop the sleep(), wait(), IO operations by throwing InterruptedExcepiton (that is why those methods throw such exception).

`ExecutorService` is using the same mechanism, so it will attempt to interrupt the running threads, but again, if your code does not check for such interruption the thread will continue running.

Due to various reasons, threads should not be simply killed (check java doc for thread.stop() method and why it is deprecated), and the "universal" way of informing the threads that maybe they should stop working is the interrupt signal.

Comment: This isn't a viable answer. The element being submitted via ExecutorService will contain code written by third parties, so we can't guarantee that internalCall will properly check Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() (as outlined in the original question). There should be a way to forcibly stop the worker without relying on the worker to be graceful - it doesn't make sense to _rely_ on graceful handling when the problem is an error case to begin with.

Comment: Don't use the executor service then and create your own thread and call stop on them. You asked about future  and executor and that is all that they offer